# django 1.5 select_for_update considered fragile design

Tags: python, django, django-database

The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#select-for-update) states

> If you were relying on “automatic transactions” to provide locking
>   between select_for_update() and a subsequent write operation — an
>   extremely fragile design, but nonetheless possible — you must wrap the
>   relevant code in atomic(). Since Django 1.6.3, executing a query with
>   select_for_update() in autocommit mode will raise a
>   TransactionManagementError.

Why is this considered fragile? I would have thought that this would result in proper transactionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aymeric clarified over email that such a design is fragile because it relies on the implicit transaction boundaries formed by Django 1.5's implicit transactions.

```
select_for_update(...)
more_code()
save()
```

This code works in straightforward cases, but if `more_code()` results in a write operation to the database, then the transaction would close, producing unintended behavior.

Forcing the user to specify the transaction boundaries also leads to clearer code.

Answer (score 10):

`select_for_update` isn't fragile.

I wrote that "if you were relying on "automatic transactions"" then you need to review your code when you upgrade from 1.5 from 1.6.

If you weren't relying on "automatic transaction", and even more if the concept doesn't ring a bell, then you don't need to do anything.

As pointed out in *yuvi*'s answer (which is very good, thank you!) Django will raise an exception when it encounters invalid code. There's no need to think about this until you see a `TransactionManagementError` raised by `select_for_update`.

Comment: First post of a core developer of the Django framework, *fiesta*! Just there to say thank you for the contribution. Hope there will be other posts from you in the future :-)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is just around the corner, in the docs for [select_for_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#select-for-update) (emphasis mine):

> Evaluating a queryset with select_for_update in autocommit mode is an
>   error because the rows are then not locked. If allowed, **this would
>   facilitate data corruption,** and could easily be caused by calling,
>   outside of any transaction, code that expects to be run in one.

In other words, there's a contradicting behaviour between `autocommit` and `select_for_update`, which can cause data corruption. Here's the [django developer's discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/8woZjCPcFmA) where they first proposed solving this issue, to quote (again, emphasis mine):

> [...] under Oracle, in autocommit mode, the automatic commit happens 
>   immediately after the command is executed -- and so, trying to fetch
>   the  results fails for being done in a separate transaction.
>
> However, **with any backend, select-for-update in autocommit mode
>   makes very  little sense. Even if it doesn't break (as it does on
>   Oracle), it doesn't  really lock anything.** So, IMO, executing a
>   query that is a select-for-update  in autocommit mode is probably en
>   error, and one that is likely to cause data-  corruption bugs.
>
> So I'm suggesting we change the behavior of select-for-update queries,
>   to  error out [...] This is a backwards-incompatible  change [...]
>   These projects should probably be thankful -- they were running with a
>   subtle bug that is now exposed -- but still.

So it was an Oracle-only bug, which shown light over a deeper problem that's relevant for all backends, and so they made the decision to make this an error in django.

`Atomic`, on the other hand, only commits things to the database after it has verifying that there are no errors, thus solving the issue.

Comment: What you've written makes sense, but the way the documentation is written suggests that the design was fragile in 1.5. "If you *were* relying on "automatic transactions"".... this to me is saying that using select_for_update in 1.5 to lock rows for update is a fragile design, even with database autocommit turned off (but still using the Django 'autocommit' application implementation)

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's only fragile when using autocommit, and it's considered as such because it **doesn't actually lock anything**. It's not fragile in a general sense. And notice - the error addresses this issue, since it's only activated on the specific case of `select_for_update` usage *with* autocommit, so it all makes sense

Comment: So is the 'extremely fragile design' comment only applicable to Django 1.6+? The way the documentation is written implies that for Django < 1.6, select_for_update is considered fragile

Comment: @Taras `select_for_update` isn't fragile on its own, only when used together with auotcommit. I'm not sure what are the implications for using it with the Django 'autocommit' app implementation. And technically, since the flawed design errors out from 1.6, then yeah, it's mostly an issue with earlier releases