# Conditional updating in Django without race condition

Tags: django, transactions

How can I update a model field based on its current value and avoid a race condition? The update task can be written as:

```
if (self.x == y):
    self.x = z
    self.save()
else:
    raise Exception()
```

However, there is a race condition. I came up with the following solution:

```
from django.db import transaction
with transaction.atomic():
    if (self.x == y):
        self.x = z
        self.save()
    else:
        raise Exception()
```

But is this safe and is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that `atomic()` block won't do anything because you've already fetched the values from the database and into `self` before you try and run the transaction.

If you can express your conditional in query arguments you could do this safely in a single query using [`update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update):

```
num_matched = MyModel.objects.filter(id=self.id, x=y).update(x=z)
if num_matched != 1:
    raise Exception()
```

If not, you can use [`select_for_update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update):

```
with transaction.atomic():
    current = MyModel.objects.select_for_update().get(id=self.id)
    if (current.x == y):
        current.x = z
        current.save()
    else:
        raise Exception()
```

The difference between this and your code above is that here you're explicitly telling the database what row to lock before doing your comparison.

Comment: First, I was wondering why you need to use `transaction.atomic` because `select_for_update` should lock the row. However, it locks only within the contex of a single transaction and each query will be its own transaction (if using autocommit), as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17149748/2184571). Therefore, you need the `transaction.atomic` wrapping, right?

Comment: @jluttine: Yes, exactly. From the documentation: "Evaluating a queryset with `select_for_update()` in autocommit mode...  is a `TransactionManagementError` error because the rows are not locked in that case."

Comment: Actually, a few questions: First, isn't `transaction.atomic` unnecessary because the only transaction after `get` is `save` and no other transactions? Second, is the `select_for_update` lock released if raising the exception? In that case, no transaction is generated so the lock isn't unreleased, or is it?

Comment: @jluttine: To really understand this you will have to read about database transactions. But briefly: 1) the `get()` and `save()` are two different operations that need to be in a transaction; by definition, autocommit puts a single operation in a transaction. 2) the `atomic()` context manager will respond to the raised exception by telling the database to roll back the transaction, which releases the lock.